# Extract Json data and verify the value using Protractor

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jasmine

I need to read the data from a Json file and then assert that the value of its keys matches with some  other values. Below is my sample code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

let StudentData = 'StudentData.json';

describe('Test for Json Data', function (){

    let Data = {

        a: 'a',
        b: 'bb',
        c: 'ccc'
    };

    let DT = JSON.stringify(Data);

    fs.writeFileSync(StudentData ,DT)


    it('test for C', function(){

        let Uploaded_data = fs.readFileSync(StudentData);

        let Data = JSON.parse(Uploaded_data);

        let c = Data['c'];

        console.log(c);

        expect(c.toBe('ccc'));

    })

});
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
 1) Test for Json Data test for C
  Message:
    Failed: c.toBe is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: c.toBe is not a function
```

How can I validate the value of "c" here?

Comment: `expect(c).toBe(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @jonrsharpe that you should `expect(c).toBe(...)`. Also there are a few other things to be careful about. I would put your methods that you want to happen before the `it` block in a `beforeAll` or `beforeEach` method to ensure that they execute before the it block.

Cleaning it up along with @jonrsharpe's comment, I would do the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const studentData = 'StudentData.json';

describe('Test for Json Data', () => {
  const data = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'bb',
    c: 'ccc'
  };

  beforeAll(() => {
    // make sure that you specify this in beforeAll or beforeEach
    fs.writeFileSync(studentData ,JSON.stringify(data))
  });

  it('test for C', () => {
    const uploadedData = fs.readFileSync(StudentData);
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(uploadedData);
    const c = parsedData['c'];
    console.log(c);
    expect(c)toBe('ccc'));
  });
});
```